# Distinguishing whether it's NTC or PTC

Tags: identification

How do we distinguish the thermal coefficient component is NTC or PTC that is one of glass bead thermistor?

Answer (score 11):

Presumably you would read the datasheet.

Lacking a datasheet, you would measure the resistance while heating or cooling the device and note if the resistance increases or decreases with an increase or decrease in temperature.

Comment: Yep, literally - take an ohmmeter and a match/soldering iron/fingers. Old school PTCs can have a "crooked" curve though, be careful...